# better system than regex

Tags: java, web-crawler

I have made an application that can extracts some specific info from a specific website. For that i have used regular expression that gives me desired output. Is there any better efficient process or idea than regex for that simple crawler.

Comment: It depends on what information you want... you could use a parser...

Comment: You haven't provided enough detail for this question to be answerable. What/how much information are you trying to extract? What code are you currently using?

Comment: To be honest, you can do the same using loops, but that process will generate lot of String objects. In my experience regex are the most speedest way, and the best way, if it can be applied.

Answer (score 2):

If you say that it is a simple regex that solves your problem, than no, there is no other more efficient solution.
When it comes to crawling, the alternative would be to load the entire html page in memory, in a DOM document and search using XPath or even XQuery. But really, if the information can be extracted easily with regex, then don't bother, especially if you are not familiar with XPath.

The power of XPath comes in when you want to make complex searches. And it is more elegant than regex, for this task(at least in w3c's oppinion). But if you want a quick solution, you already found it, and it is more efficient in terms of RAM too.

Comment: But what happened to the whole "you can't use regexes for HTML" concept?

Comment: @Mr Lister It's not "you can't", it's "you shouldn't". It is still valid. But if you just want a simple fast thing, then it is ok. This concept is based on the fact that the html can change and it would require you to also change the code. But that is sometimes also true for other solutions. If you are doing some intense scraping then you should stay away from parsing with regex.